# NSXMLParser Outputting "XMLElement: 0x8d61200" but want "XMLElement: Richard"

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, nsxmlparser

I am trying to figure out the NSXMLParser, & I am not sure why this isn't working. I should be out putting the First & Last name as well as the age but it is outputing a number.

The XML is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<root>

<person id="1">

    <firstName>Anthony</firstName>

    <lastName>Robbins</lastName>

    <age>51</age>

</person>

<person id="2">

    <firstName>Richard</firstName>

    <lastName>Branson</lastName>

    <age>61</age>

 </person>

</root>
```

In my AppDelegate.m i have

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "XMLElement.h"

@interface AppDelegate () <NSXMLParserDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSXMLParser *xmlParser;

@property (nonatomic, strong) XMLElement *rootElement;

@property (nonatomic, strong) XMLElement *currentElementPointer;

@end



@implementation AppDelegate



- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions

{

NSString *xmlFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"MyHTML"
                                                        ofType:@"HTML"];

NSData *xml = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:xmlFilePath];

self.xmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:xml];

self.xmlParser.delegate = self;

if ([self.xmlParser parse]){

    NSLog(@"The XML is parsed.");


    /* self.rootElement is now the root element in the XML */

    XMLElement *element = self.rootElement.subElements[1];

    NSLog(@"%@", element.subElements);



} else{

    NSLog(@"Failed to parse the XML");

}

self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:

               [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

return YES;

}

- (void)parserDidStartDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser{

self.rootElement = nil;

self.currentElementPointer = nil;

}

  - (void)        parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser

    didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName

       namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI

      qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName

         attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict{

  if (self.rootElement == nil){

    /* We don't have a root element. Create it and point to it */

    self.rootElement = [[XMLElement alloc] init];

    self.currentElementPointer = self.rootElement;

  } else {

    /* Already have root. Create new element and add it as one of

     the subelements of the current element */

    XMLElement *newElement = [[XMLElement alloc] init];

    newElement.parent = self.currentElementPointer;

    [self.currentElementPointer.subElements addObject:newElement];

    self.currentElementPointer = newElement;

  }

  self.currentElementPointer.name = elementName;

  self.currentElementPointer.attributes = attributeDict;

  }


  - (void)        parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser

    foundCharacters:(NSString *)string{

if ([self.currentElementPointer.text length] > 0){

    self.currentElementPointer.text =

    [self.currentElementPointer.text stringByAppendingString:string];

} else {

    self.currentElementPointer.text = string;

  }
}


  - (void)        parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser

      didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName

       namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI

      qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName{



self.currentElementPointer = self.currentElementPointer.parent;
 }


- (void)parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser{

self.currentElementPointer = nil;

 }
```

In my XMLElement class is

```
 #import "XMLElement.h"
@implementation XMLElement


- (NSMutableArray *) subElements{

if (_subElements == nil){

    _subElements = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

}

return _subElements;

}
@end
```

I am getting as my problem

2013-11-21 15:59:53.216 XML[7595:70b] The XML is parsed.
2013-11-21 15:59:53.219 XML[7595:70b] (
"XMLElement: 0x8d61200",
"XMLElement: 0x8d61270",
"XMLElement: 0x8d612e0"
)
2013-11-21 15:59:53.223 XML[7595:70b] Application windows are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch

I want to get

2013-11-21 15:59:53.216 XML[7595:70b] The XML is parsed.
2013-11-21 15:59:53.219 XML[7595:70b] (
"XMLElement: Richard ",
"XMLElement: Branson ",
"XMLElement: 61 "
)
2013-11-21 15:59:53.223 XML[7595:70b] Application windows are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch

Comment: Hi and welcome! Just a small request, if I may? Any chance you could reduce the amount of code in the question - just to the relevant parts? Otherwise it is a lot of code to read to help solve a problem that is probably fairly simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you set it up:

```
#import "XMLElement.h"
@implementation XMLElement

- (NSMutableArray *) subElements {
    if (_subElements == nil){
        _subElements = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
    return _subElements;
 }

- (NSString *)description {
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:"XMLElement: %@", self.text];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the default description method is used to print your objects.
In that case you should override that method in the `XMLElement` class, for example

```
- (NSString *)description
{
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:"XMLElement: %@", self.text];
}
```